# Which RAID to use for 8 hard drives?

Tags: raid

I have 8 idendical hard drives and I want to know which RAID levels or level combinations I should use to achieve maximum performancefor random reverse reading.

Comment: Give more information! Which Server / RAID Controller / HDDs / Controller Cache Module / etc. ? Also more detailed information about what this server will do would be nice!

Comment: What is "random reverse reading"?

Answer (score 5):

For that many disks there's really only two options but your mention of performance narrows that to one.

RAID 6 would be the choice for getting the most capacity out of that many disks safely.
RAID 10 would the choice for getting the most performance out of that many disks safely.

It's as simple as that.